# Knockout JS - On click load modal edit form for the item selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I apologize in advance for the lenghty explanation. I have a web application that loads a grid of records. Each grid row shows only portions of the total record. The user is presented with an Edit button on the grid for each row records. So far I have my web applications fully working with JQuery but after I found out about Knockout js I needed to implement it to my web application.

With KO I set the `data-bind="attr: { 'data-ID': ID }"` on the button to identify what record is being edited. I am then able to grab the ID of the button and pass it on to my function as such:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit_button", function() {
var Button_ID = $(this).data("id");
IncidentManager.showIncidentDetails(Button_ID); 
$('#myModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
});
```

Clicking the Edit button would shows a modal and displays an editor revealing all the fields of the record they selected. This is the part I am having the most trouble with. With JQuery I can accomplish this part by using the code below. But I am not understanding how to implement this with knockout js, can't figure out how to tell knockout to reveal all the fields of the record the user selected.

```
// This function will loadup the data into the modal form,
showIncidentDetails: function (Button_ID) {
    if (Button_ID == null) return;

    $.ajax({
        url: this.basePath()+'/GDI_PROD_Incidents('+Button_ID+')',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

        $('#DeleteButton').show();

        $.each(data, function (index, incident) {

            $('#Incident_ID').val(incident.ID);
            $('#Description').val(incident.Description);
            $('#Composante').selectpicker('val', incident.Composante.split(","));
            $('#Incident').val(incident.Incident);
            $('#état').find('option[value="'+incident.ÉtatValue+'"]').attr("selected",true);
            $('#Priorité').find('option[value="'+incident.PrioritéValue+'"]').attr("selected",true);
            $('#Duré').val(incident.Duré);
            $('#DateDeDébut').val(incident.Date_de_début);
            $('#DateDeFin').val(incident.Date_de_fin);
            $('#support').selectpicker('val', incident.Groupe_Support_Prime.split(","));

            $('#Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime').attr('value', incident.Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime);
            $('#Prime').find('option[value="'+incident.ResponsableValue+'"]').attr("selected",true);
            $('#Impact').val(incident.Impact);
            $('#Temps_Consacré').attr('value', incident.Temps_Consacré);
            $('#Type_de_temps').find('option[value="'+incident.Type_de_tempsValue+'"]').attr("selected",true);
            $('#Journal_des_actions').val(incident.Journal_des_actions);
            $('#Dépannage_effectué').val(incident.Dépanage);
            $('#Suivi').val(incident.Suivi);
            $('#Ressources').val(incident.Ressources);

        });
        }
    });

},
```

This is the knockout code I have written so far:

```
<script type="text/html" id="Incidents">
<tr>
    <td class='over_flow_control'><button class='edit_button btn btn-default btn-sm' type='button' value='Edit' data-bind="attr: { 'data-ID': ID }"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i></button></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control' data-bind="text:Incident"></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control'><h4><span class='priorité_span' data-bind="text:PrioritéValue"></span></h4></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control' data-bind="text:Composante"></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control text-left' data-bind="text:Description"></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control Date_de_début_cell' data-bind="text:Date_de_début"></td>
    <td class='over_flow_control' data-bind="text:ResponsableValue"></td>    
</tr>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load_active_incidents() {
         var self = this;
         self.ActiveIncidents = ko.observableArray([]);
         $.getJSON("../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc/GDI_PROD_Incidents?$filter=ÉtatValue%20ne%20%27Fermé%27&$orderby=PrioritéValue desc",function (data) {
         if (data.d.results) {
            self.ActiveIncidents(ko.toJS(data.d.results));
         }
        }
       );
     }
     $(document).ready(function () {
         ko.applyBindings(new load_active_incidents());
     });
 </script>
```

I would really appreciate any help at this point.

Answer (score 1):

For each different element of state in your view, you're going to want to have an observable in your viewmodel. For example, your `DeleteButton` should have a `visible` binding:

```
<button data-bind="visible:showDeleteButton">...
```

You usually don't need to have ids on elements when using Knockout because you don't have to select them to fiddle with them. You change what they're bound to and Knockout updates the element.

Where you have things like

```
$('#Incident_ID').val(incident.ID);
```

You would do something like

```
incidentId(incident.ID);
```

in your viewmodel, where `incidentId` is an observable. Have you gone through [the Knockout tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/)? The documentation is quite good and the tutorials are very helpful for getting an understanding of how to do things.

Comment: Thanks for the info Roy, i've been scanning trough the the Knockout and learning as I go. Most of it well covered but can't seem to find how to edit the selected items in a modal form. after digging a bit more I found 2 examples on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WpnTU/ and http://jsfiddle.net/mac2000/N2zNk/light/ studying the code to see how its done.

Comment: This doesn't use a modal, but the principle is the same. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ACE2d/